# Using Promise when extracting data from Supabase into React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, supabase

223e3232e2['l3emlp23me2l3;
em3l;2em3l2;[e32e23

Comment: This has solved my problem thank you, but how would I then go into the object result further? With this solution I can't do console.log(result[0]["username"] to get the "username" field

Comment: You can provide a custom function instead of console.log. Eg, `getUserValue("", "").then(result => { console.log(result[0].username) })`

Comment: @NicholasTower Also how can I then store the value as a variable?

Comment: Since this is a react component, you probably want to put it in state, so it can be used by the rest of the component. See phil's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to store data in React components is to [define and set state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

The correct place to handle side-effects like async response data is in an [effect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

```jsx
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Sidebar(props) {
  const [ user, setUser ] = useState(null); // initial value

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserValue("", "")
      .then(users => {
        setUser(users[0]) // your response is an array, extract the first value
      })
      .catch(console.error)
  }, []); // empty array means run this once on mount

  return user && ( // only display if `user` is set
    <p>Hello, { user.username }</p> {/* just an example */}
  );
}
```

---

<sub>I feel like this has definitely been asked and answered before but I couldn't find an applicable duplicate. Happy to remove this or mark it Community Wiki if somebody can link an existing post.</sub>